# HTML: cursor showing in readonly input text?

Tags: html, input, readonly

Let's say we have a textbox that's readonly, like so:

```
<input type="text" readonly />
```

In IE 9 and FF 4, when I click on this field, a (non-blinking) cursor appears in the field. In Chrome, however, the cursor does not show. (See for yourself at http://jsfiddle.net/hqBsW/.)

I suppose I understand why IE/FF opt to show the cursor—so the user knows he or she can still select the value in the field.

Nonetheless, it's evidently confusing our users and we would like to change IE/FF to not show the cursor, as Chrome does for `readonly` fields.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I also faced the same problem and I got the solution. Write the `pointer-events: none;` CSS property for that input field.

Comment: Have a look on this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45738397/hide-text-field-blinking-cursor-in-ie-or-even-change-blinking-cursor-color-to-wh/51328027#51328027

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sounds like a bug!

There is [a similar bug (396542)](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=396542) open with Mozilla, saying that the cursor *should* blink in `readonly` inputs — but that behavior feels wrong, a blinking cursor is supposed to mean, “you can type here.”

You should comment on that bug and/or file new ones (with Mozilla [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi) and with Microsoft [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/IE))!

In the meantime, using `disabled` or changing the behavior with JavaScript, as @nikmd23 suggested, seems like the best workaround.

Comment: One note about disabled fields, is that disabled fields are not posted to the server in a form post.

Comment: In regard to the above comment - there is of course the dirty hack of putting a hidden and disabled element in the form.

Comment: Disabling a field for a readonly listbox/combobox is not desirable. Therefore, you need readonly state without disbling it. http://w3c.github.io/aria/#listbox and http://w3c.github.io/aria/#combobox

Comment: Write the `pointer-events: none;` CSS property for that input field.

Answer (score 19):

My solution, from nikmd23's jQuery snippet but with the blur() function that seems to work better

```
$('input[readonly]').focus(function(){
    this.blur();
});
```

[Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/eAZa2/](http://jsfiddle.net/eAZa2/)

Don't use the attribute "disabled" because the input would not be submitted when it is part of a form

Comment: I wanted to know if it matters how readonly was used: http://jsfiddle.net/m7saqqpL/ it seems that it does not make a difference.

Comment: Yes, they look like the same because both fields are not editable (another small difference is the color of the text, on disabled fields it's dark gray but it could depend on browsers). The main difference is when you post your forms to the server, an input with the attribute "disabled" will not be submitted at all while a "readonly" input will.

Comment: The onfocus="this.blur()" does not seem to work in IE11

Comment: When changing the "readonly" attribute dynamically, use:  `$('input').focus(function(){ if ($(this).is('[readonly]')) this.blur()});`

Answer (score 8):

If you change the `readonly` attribute to `disabled`, you won't be able to click into the input box and thus won't have a cursor.

Depending on the browser, you may not be able to select the text either though.

I've provided examples of the various input states here: http://jsfiddle.net/hqBsW/1/

Another alternative is you could force a text selection when the user focuses on a given input element. This change in control behavior would more easily clue the user into the fact that input is restricted, and allows them to copy very easily if that is the end use case.

Using jQuery you would write the selection code like this:

```
$('input[readonly]').focus(function(){
    this.select();
});
```

I've updated the example to show this behavior in action: http://jsfiddle.net/hqBsW/2/

Comment: Sometimes you need the readonly attribute versus disabled. In HTML5, you can't validate disabled fields, but you can validate readonly fields.

Answer (score 6):

It can be done using html and javascript

```
<input type="text" onfocus="this.blur()" readonly >
```

or globally using jQuery

```
$(document).on('focus', 'input[readonly]', function () {
        this.blur();
    });
```

Answer (score 6):

For a `CSS` only fix, use :

```
input[readonly] {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the only way i found for this was

```
//FIREFOX
$('INPUT_SELECTOR').focus(function () {
                $(this).blur();
            });
//INTERNET EXPLORER
$('INPUT_SELECTOR').attr('unselectable', 'on');
KENDO
$('.k-ff .k-combobox>span>.k-input').focus(function () {
                $(this).blur();
            });
$('.k-ie .k-combobox>span>.k-input').attr('unselectable', 'on');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `css`:

```
input {pointer-events:none;}
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

Comment: Welcome to SO. When answering a question, please provide explanation associated with your code. Some people might not understand your code or don't see how it answers the question. See [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score -2):

You can set the style attribute of your tag or you can add a css class to your tag by setting the class attribute's value. Your problem can be solved by setting the cursor. You can read more [here](http://www.echoecho.com/csscursors.htm). Also, if you have some rules which set the cursor of this tag you can add !important to your css rule. You can read more about !important [here](http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/f/blcssfaqimportn.htm).

Comment: The question is asking about a text cursor, not the mouse cursor.