# Avoid readOnly textbox being clicked in Firefox

Tags: html, firefox, browser, click

How to avoid readonly textbox being clicked in firefox ?

In Firefox the textbox with readOnly attribute can be clicked where as other browsers don't..
It gives the user an intention that textbox can be written..

How can it be avoided in firefox ?

Note:

I don't want to disable the field..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7917592/html-cursor-showing-in-readonly-input-text

Comment: is there limitation writing javascript?if not you can do it easily with js.

Comment: @Behnam Esmaili : What we can do it in js ?

Answer (score 7):

Use CSS

```
[readonly]{
    cursor: auto;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}​
```

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/rR6dk/2/

Comment: it is not working in fire Fox, i can able to click on the text box element.. if you see in Google chorme it works perfect.

Answer (score 2):

you can use javascript to take focus out of input.

```
$("input").focus(function(){
       $(this).blur();
});
```

and use css to style your input so give the user intention that input has been disabled.

**EDIT:**

check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MFCDeveloper/XzcuH/13/)

Comment: i asked him whether he can use js or not.

Comment: yep this is far the best for all browsers Benham

Answer (score 1):

You can just add this CSS. Just for firefox:

```
[readonly]{
    cursor: default;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}​
```

It works!

Comment: it is not working even in firefox, i can able to click on the text box element.. if you see in Google chorme it works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

just disable the textbox.

```
<input type='text' disabled='disabled' />
```

Comment: @Jusnit - what is it about `disabled` that you don't want? because if you want the field to be un-clickable, disabled will do it. If the problem is the way it looks, you can style the disabled field so it doesn't look disabled.

Comment: @Spudley: I will explain, I have created custom combobox based on [ui combobox](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox) in jquery. Here some problem in disabled field,  focus, blur etc.. don't work as it was expected, whereas readonly work perfectly...

Comment: let me understand: do you want a textbox that readonly (UN-chanchable) and UN-clickable? If you do, disable and re-color the textbox
disable is something like readonly, but it has different colors