# why readonly not worked in IE 8 and IE 9?

Tags: html, css

HTML, readonly not worked in IE 8 and IE 9, if any other way to solve,

here is my code,

```
<input
  size="15"
  type="text"
  name="oldValueMonthlyLimit"
  id="oldValueMonthlyLimit"
  readonly =true
  value="<%=oldValueMonthlyLimit%>">
```

Comment: You're not using it properly. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_readonly.asp

Comment: @Vucko still its not working, any other solution

Comment: Is the value="<%=oldValueMonthlyLimit%>" working ?

Comment: @Vucko , oldValueMonthlyLimit is working , but readonly not working. its working in IE 7

Comment: @ raja I tested the code with value="text" in IE8 and it's working. I think that there is the problem. http://jsfiddle.net/eQsxU/

Comment: @Vucko - readonly is working, that means, if i click- cursor is pointed in that text box but edit is not allowed, i agreed this ,but i want the solution is if i click - even cursor also not allowed in that text box, same as IE 7-

Comment: I have to say that, it is casesentitive. You can try **readOnly** with **O** in uppercase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use disabled then.

```
<input
size="15"
type="text"
name="oldValueMonthlyLimit"
id="oldValueMonthlyLimit"
disabled value="text" >
```

[Link](http://jsfiddle.net/eQsxU/2/)

See also this:
[Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7917592/html-cursor-showing-in-readonly-input-text)

Comment: attention. Disabled and readonlly have different behavior: *disable* fields does not POST values, but *readonly* does!

Comment: disabled also won't allow focus or highlighting the text value

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `readonly="readonly"`?

Comment: did u mean <input
  size="15"
  type="text"
  name="oldValueMonthlyLimit"
  id="oldValueMonthlyLimit"
  readonly ="readonly"
  value="<%=oldValueMonthlyLimit%>"> ?

Comment: @raja: Yes. Yes, I did. [damn 15 char limit]

Comment: readonly is working, that means, if i click- cursor is pointed in that text box but edit is not allowed, i agreed this ,but i want the solution is if i click - even cursor also not allowed in that text box, same as IE 7-

Answer (score 1):

The 'disabled' input elements are used to prevent its value from being submitted.

'readonly' input element doesn't work in IE 8,9, 10 or 11.

In this case, we can use **onkeydown="javascript: return false;"** for protected (disable) input element and receive its value in the form post data

Answer (score 0):

From w3schools:

```
<input readonly="readonly">
```

Note: The readonly attribute is a boolean attribute, and can be set in the following ways:

```
<input readonly>
<input readonly="readonly">
<input readonly="">
```

Comment: readonly is working, that means, if i click- cursor is pointed in that text box but edit is not allowed, i agreed this ,but i want the solution is if i click - even cursor also not allowed in that text box, same as IE 7-

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<input type="text" onfocus="this.blur()" readonly="" >
```

Also in CSS, put this to make the cursor not change while hovering over the input.

```
cursor: inherit;
```

Comment: cursor: inherit; not worked always. using cursor: default; suits more i think.