# Cursor is showed in readonly input text firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, input, readonly

I need a readonly input text, and the cursor is not supposed to be displayed.
It works fine in chrome, but it keeps showing in Firefox.
I need it to be displayed in Firefox as the exact as Chrome.

```
<input type="text" readonly />
```

I followed this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7917592/html-cursor-showing-in-readonly-input-text) in stackoverflow, but it does not work the same as chrome.
Is there a workaround to make it the same as Chrome.

Comment: Keep in mind that when you using `disabled="disabled"` the user cannot copy the input value exept chrome.

Comment: Exactly, I have to use readonly attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code this is a same functionality as readonly

1 `<input type="text" disabled="disabled" value="testing" />`

Comment: If disabled attribute is used,then the item is unclickable moreover you can't copy it's contents.

Answer (score 0):

beside setting "disabled" instead of "readonly", you might set the cursor via CSS: `input[readonly]{ cursor: default; }`