# How not to display blinking text cursor, in read only, textarea through JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

On an event, The texarea is set to readonly. But when user click it, it shows text cursor blinking in textarea.

```
<textarea readonly="readonly"></textarea>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/foeyo7qc/

**Requirement**:
The textarea should be readonly (not disabled); but on click of it the text cursor should not be displayed blinking.

is there any way to do it through jQuery?

**Update**:

Browser: IE-10+
Mozilla Latest
Chrome Latest

Comment: In what browser, my Chrome doesn't show a cursor at all ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hide textfield blinking cursor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3671141/hide-textfield-blinking-cursor)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7917592/html-cursor-showing-in-readonly-input-text

Comment: like https://jsfiddle.net/foeyo7qc/2/ ?

Comment: Does it have to be a `textarea`? Maybe you can replace it with a `div` as long as it's readonly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following snippet helped me in resolving it:

```
$('textarea').on('mouseover', function (e) {
        $(this).is('[readonly]') ? $(this).addClass("cursorNotAllowed") : $(this).removeClass("cursorNotAllowed");
    });

    $('textarea').focus(function(){
        $(this).is('[readonly]') ? this.blur() : "";
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your `<textarea>` tag or class:

```
textarea{
    ...
    color : transparent;
}
```

This should fake the effect you want.

**EDIT**

Useless if you need to insert some text.

Comment: It also makes any text in the textarea invisible

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `font-size` to 0,
You'll have to set a `height` and a `width` for the `<textarea>` now though

```
textarea{
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    font-size : 0;
}
```