# Force Text Caret To Appear In Readonly Input

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, dom-events

Scenario: When an input field is set `.readOnly = true`, the text cursor is replaced with the pointer arrow cursor and the input field cannot be entered or modified. However, clicking into such a readonly input field with text in it does actually register the cursor's location within the text, even though the display does not show the clicked location by visually rendering a text cursor caret, like a read-enabled input field would.

Here's the question: Is there a way to force the text cursor caret to appear in an input field set `.readOnly = true`, in other words, as if the input field were actually read enabled, but still keep the input field readonly?

Answer (score 2):

What you want to achieve is actually an existing bug in few browsers.

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7917592/html-cursor-showing-in-readonly-input-text)

But you can achieve this by below workaround.

Remove `readOnly` attribute and try with below code

```js
$('document').ready(function() {
  $('input[type="text"]').keydown(function(e) {
    return false;
  });

  $('input[type="text"]').bind("cut copy paste", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="some value" />
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this with css :

```
input[readonly] {
  cursor: text;
}
```

or

```
<input type="text" style="cursor: text;">
```

Comment: The question was about text cursor caret, not about mouse pointer cursor, which can have a styling type of caret but thats a different thing. 

But I see how it can be confusing.