# IE 11 readonly input field is editable on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I noticed an issue while working with jquery on IE 11.The problem is Imade some input elements readonly in my form.But in IE 10,11 I noticed that cursor is on the readonly input field and able to editable for the first time.But when I click on somewhere or tab button it is working as expected.Please Let me know what was wrong???

Comment: What has jQuery to do with `readonly` `<input>` elements? Where is your little bit of code we can look at?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML: cursor showing in readonly input text?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7917592/html-cursor-showing-in-readonly-input-text)

Comment: jQuery(".class1").closest("tr").find("input").attr("readonly",true); for the first  time cursor is on the readonly field and am able to type the value into that.On other browsers it is working fine

Comment: I would advise using `.prop()` versus `.attr()`. Also can you set the `readonly` attribute manually? It would be helpful to include a  complete example in your post.

Comment: tried that also ..still not working