# Hide text field blinking cursor in IE or even change blinking cursor color to white

Tags: javascript, html, css, input

How to hide input field blinking cursor in IE.

This is not duplicate since there are many similar question on but so far i have seen does not works in IE.

When I simply use this css it works fine chrome and Firefox but in IE it only hides character not blinking cursor.

```
.hideChar{
   color: white !important;
}
```

At the same time I don't want to do blur or change cursor position because in input field value is continuously coming I just want to hide that character and cursor not alter value or cursor position.

Comment: It sounds to me like you want to use an input element for something that is not actual input. If you don't want the value or cursor position to change then you might as well use a normal text element that doesn't have the cursor to start with.

Comment: Perhaps I'm not understanding your issue correctly though... Why exactly are you wanting to hide the cursor and prevent any value changes?

Comment: Hi @Lix I am trying to scan in the input field that scanner gives me long string which should not be visible to user so i want to hide everything till scan is over in that field

Comment: Though i am able to hide character and cursor in chrome and Firefox but in IE only character is hidden cursor is visible, its not that always i want to hide character user can even enter value manually in that case cursor should not be hidden

Comment: `<input type="hidden">` until scan is done?

Comment: Do you mean like a barcode scanner?

Comment: Hi @LeeKowalkowski this will hide input field itself not character

Comment: Yes @LeeKowalkowski Barcode scanner

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/caret-color ?

Comment: @LeeKowalkowski caret-color this property is not supported in IE i already tried this

Comment: So, why do you need the caret to be hidden?

Comment: @LeeKowalkowski when values are coming from scanner it should not be shown in filed that's done and at same time it is visible that caret is moving in input field which looks wired that value is not present in field still caret is moving

Comment: I don't know much about scanners, etc, but how can you tell the difference between the input coming from a scanner, and the input is being pasted or manually entered?

Comment: Otherwise, you could just hide the whole field (e.g. off-screen co-ordinates) such fields can still be focused using their labels.

Answer (score 3):

I got the same problem and here is your solution
Write `pointer-events: none;` CSS property for that input field.

Here is the solution http://jsfiddle.net/hqBsW/488/

In this example, this readonly input field will not show blink cursor in the IE browser.